# How to handle errors met when running ASP.NET applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am using VS2005 C#, and I have an application which has a few functions like list, edit database, import and export of data.

However, I have no clue of catching and handling errors. Below is a sample screenshot of an error met when the column of a file imported does not match with the database, and stops the application from running and points straight to my backend code:
[image]

Preiovusly I am using Netbeans and it clearer to me in Netbeans because they always specify each error with an error code, so I was able to assign a webpage for each individual error code.

May I know how can I identify these errors and how can I handle them? Is it possible to assign a webpage redirection when an error is met?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three ways to handle exceptions in ASP.NET:

```
            1. All the exceptions will catch  page level.
            2. All the exceptions will catch entire site level.
            3. All the exceptions will catch by using "web.config" file
```

## Examples:

**1.Exception Handling at page level.**

```
       public void Page_Error(object obj, EventArgs ergs)
        {

            Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
            string err = "Error Caught in Application_Error event " +    
                         System.Environment.NewLine + "Error in: " + Request.Url.ToString() +
                         System.Environment.NewLine + "Error Occured Time:" + DateTime.Now +
                         System.Environment.NewLine + "Error Message:" + objErr.Message.ToString() +
                         System.Environment.NewLine + "Stack Trace:" + objErr.StackTrace.ToString();
            Response.Write(err);
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Redirect("~/customError.aspx");
        }
```

**2.Exception Handling at website level.**

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
            TraceExceptions objExceptionInsert = new  TraceExceptions();
            objExceptionInsert.StackTrace = objErr.StackTrace;
            objExceptionInsert.Exception = objErr.Message;
            objExceptionInsert.Page = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
           //Inserting exception into the database
            int exceptioncode = Utilities.TraceException(objExceptionInsert);
            Server.ClearError();
           //Redirecting to common exception page
            string url = "~/Common/Exceptions.aspx?ExceptionCode=" + exceptioncode;
            Response.Redirect(url);

        }
```

**3.Exception Handling at website level by using web.config.**

The customErrors element of the web.config file is the last line of defense against an unhandled error. If you have other error handlers in place, like the Application_Error of Page_Error subs, these will get called first. Provided they don't do a Response.Redirect or a Server.ClearError, you should be brought to the page(s) defined in the web.config. In the web.config file, you can handle specific error codes (500, 404, etc), or you can use one page to handle all errors. This is a major difference between this method and the others (although you can emulate this by doing various Response.Redirects using the other methods). Open up your web.config file. The customErrors section uses this format:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="url" mode="On|Off|RemoteOnly">
   <error statusCode="statuscode" redirect="url"/>
</customErrors>
```

Here is some important information about the "mode" attribute:
"On" specifies that custom errors are enabled. If no defaultRedirect is specified, users see a generic error.

"Off" specifies that custom errors are disabled. This allows display of detailed errors.

"RemoteOnly" specifies that custom errors are shown only to remote clients, and ASP.NET errors are shown to the local host. This is the default.

By default, the section looks like this when you create a Web application.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may redirect the users on unhandled errors. Take a look at MSDN article - [Complete Example for Error Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx).

PS: Read Code project article - [Exception Handling Best Practices in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/exceptionbestpractices.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy to follow article [here](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030102.htm).

And [here](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/advanced/exceptions/).

At it's most basic, error handling in .NET is done with a try...catch...finally structure, similar to Java.  You mentioned using NetBeans, so I assume you're familiar with Java exception handling using these structures, so it should be a fairly simple transition once you understand the basics.

There is a difference between catching exception codes, and exception types.  For example, in .NET, you might get a `System.NullReferenceException`, or a `FileNotFoundException`. For the most part, exceptions are very well-named, which makes understanding what went wrong a bit easier.  It's just something different to get used to.

The error in your screenshot is an OleDbException, which means something went wrong with the OleDb command, connection, etc.  You can click the "More Details".

Also, once you know the Exception type, **the best first place to look is on MSDN**, where you can usually find very good documentation on causes, solutions, etc.  For example, your error is covered here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbexception.aspx

Finally, if you notice in your screenshot, the error dialog includes a link to "search for more help online".  This will often take you right where you need to go to fix your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Application_Error` event handler in the `Global.asax` file to catch all unhandled errors in your ASP.Net application.

```
    protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().InnerException;

        Application["Ex"] = ex;
        Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx")
    }
```

where `ErrorPage.aspx` fetches the `Ex` value and display or handle it. There is another example from [this site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355).

Also, from the screen shot you've given, you may click on the `View Detail` link and you will be given the call stack, inner exception (if any), and any other information that will help you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Error catching is pretty strait forward in c#, something like:

```
try{
    //stuff you think might fail here, for instance the stuff inside your using statement
}
catch(Exception e){
    Response.Redirect("/myErrorPage.aspx?error=" + e.Message);
}
```

Once you have caught an exception you can get all sorts of info about it from the exception object (e in this case)

Comment: Yes, finally  could be useful, though in the code above, the using statement will take care of any db connections that need to be closed